# Windows multiple rabbitmq locally

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I'd like to have multiple instances of rabbitmq running on my developement machine. It seems like I can only install one rabbitmq service, so I'm wondering how can I spawn multiple rabbitmq processes ?

My objective is to launch and kill "n" rabbitmq node locally via c# in my automated integration test.

Comment: I think you need to look up virtual hosts.  I am not 100% but it might be a solution to what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to kill the nodes you could create multiple RabbitMQ nodes on your local machine which run under the same service.

You can find more information [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine). Although this is under the 'Clustering' documentation, you should be able to create multiple nodes and just skip the 'clustering' bit.

Comment: I went with this option. I'm building wrapper code around the all the .bat files to start, stop and monitor nodes.